# EXT JS how to get data

Tags: extjs

I'm a first time learner of EXT Js and on the example http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#array-grid I'm trying to find out how the table is being populated and can't find the source of the content of the table.
Anyone who's used EXT Js before should find it trivial to find the source of the data or recommend how and if it's possible to test extjs on a platform like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many procedure by which you can get data for the grid.

First way is binding data to the code itself.

But before that how to bind data and how it work in grid, You need to create your `data store` and then bind this store to your grid in `store`.

Here is an example code :

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Here is sencha fiddle for you.
[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22ik)

The second way where you can fetch data from JSON or XML. In this case also you have to create a `data store`(Which may be json store or Array store) and again binding to the grid. Only data part will change. Here you need to fetch data from the json by using some ajax call.

Here is the example code.

```
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        storeId: 'myStore',

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-images.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'images'
            }
        },

    //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
    fields: ['name', 'url', {name:'size', type: 'float'}, {name:'lastmod', type:'date'}]
});
```

and then call your bind your store as we did in previous code.
 I will suggest you to please  go through this links

Usefull link

[Grid PAnel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html) _ Grid Panel
[Data Store](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-data) - Data Store
[JSON STore](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.2/api/Ext.data.JsonStore.html)